# MongoDB get all entries between 2 timestamps

Tags: mongodb, date

I'm new to MongoDB and have to work with records that look like this (shortened):

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "a856f4sf48b84ab48s"
    },
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2020-11-18T12:42:41.458Z"
    },
    "subset": {
        "subTimestamp": {
            "$date": "2020-11-18T14:01:25.340Z"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get all records where the `subTimestamp` is lower than `createdAt` date + 2 minutes.

So I tried the following 2 versions but they won't work (I'm working with the filter function in the MongoDB Compass App):

```
{"subset.subTimestamp": {$lte: {$add: ["$createdAt", 120000]}}}

{"subset.subTimestamp": {$lte: createdAt + 120000}}
```

What works is

```
{"subset.subTimestamp": {$lte: new Date() + 120000}}
```

So I assume I do something wrong when handling 2 dates. Maybe it has something to do with the `$date`?

Comment: Two things look potentially strange here.  First of all, your date field really called `"$date"` with a `$` in it?  Second, are your date fields actually of the date type, or are they just text?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that's the normal [MongoDB Extended JSON (v1)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json-v1/#bson.data_date) format for `Date` values

Comment: Then I don't have an explanation why the first version be not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like to compare with existing data, you must use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html):

```
db.collection.find({ $expr: { $lte: ["$subset.subTimestamp", { $add: ["$createdAt", 1000 * 60 * 2] } ]} })
```

Note, 120000 is 2 Minutes but the actual time difference in your sample data is 1 Hour 20 Minutes!

Comment: Am I doing something wrong [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RObie5CARp8)?

Comment: No, it's all correct. You query for documents where "$subset.subTimestamp" <= $createdAt + 2 Minutes. You don't get any documents, because the difference is more than 1 hour!

Comment: Thanks! The query works on Mongo Playground. Unfortunately MongoDB Compass can't handle $expr, it quits with "unknown operator: $expr"